# Number of weekends between two NSDates

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Assuming that we are using a Gregorian calendaring system, what's the best method to work out the number of weekends which have occurred between two `NSDate` objects?

My current approach involves working out the number of days between the two `NSDate`s then dividing by 7 and `floor()`ing the result. This gives me the number of weeks and, as a result, the number of weekends. Because we are `floor`ing the result if the week is not yet complete (and there is a remainder on the division) it ignores that and only considers full weeks which have past.

Any suggestions for improvement and robustness would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, the description of code are there in comments:-

```
//Assuming this is your dates where you need to determine the weekend in between two dates
NSString *strDate1=@"10-01-2014";
NSString *strDate2=@"19-01-2014";
NSDateFormatter *format=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dt1=[format dateFromString:strDate1];
NSDate *dt2=[format dateFromString:strDate2];

//Now finding the days between two dates
NSUInteger units = NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar *cal = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *com=[cal components:units fromDate:dt1 toDate:dt2 options:0];
NSInteger day1=[com day];
int i=0;
int j=0;


//Now calculating how many weekends(Sat, Sun) are there in the total number of days.
for(i=0; i<=day1; i++)
{
    com=[[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    [com setDay:i];
    NSDate *newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                       dateByAddingComponents:com
                       toDate:dt1 options:0];
    [format setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
    NSString *satSun=[format stringFromDate:newDate];
    if ([satSun isEqualToString:@"Sat"] || [satSun isEqualToString:@"Sun"])
    {
        j++;

    }
}
        NSLog(@"Total number of weekends found= %d",j);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you note your solution may return a value one less than the actual number of weekends.

To account for the possible extra weekend if the remainder of the total days after dividing by 7 is greater than 0 then compare the weekday number (e.g. `NSDateComponents`'s `weekday` - which is 1 for Sunday through 7 for Saturday) of the starting and ending dates. If the ending weekday number is less than starting one there must be a weekend in between (counting the Sat/Sun change as the weekend - adjust as you see fit).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick implementation:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1209600];
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:kNilOptions];
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSArray *weekend = [fmt weekdaySymbols];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == 'Saturday' || SELF == 'Sunday'"];
NSArray *weekendArr = [weekend filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
NSString *weekendsStr = [weekendArr componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSDateComponents *compsWithDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[compsWithDay setDay:1];
NSString *dayNameStr = [fmt stringFromDate:startDate];
NSUInteger count = 0;
if ([weekendsStr rangeOfString:dayNameStr].location != NSNotFound) {
  count++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < comps.day; i++) {
  startDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:compsWithDay toDate:startDate options:kNilOptions];
  dayNameStr = [fmt stringFromDate:startDate];
  if ([weekendsStr rangeOfString:dayNameStr].location != NSNotFound) {
    count++;
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. This code is supposed to be used only with ARC enabled
2. Maybe there is redundancy, cannot see it right now. But code works correctly.